# Better way of retrieving info from XML file using XPATH

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I've got so far a very simple class named Menu.php which contains the following:

```
<?php
class Menu
{
    private $_dom;
    private $categoryItems;

    function __construct()
    {
        if(file_exists('Menu.xml'))
        {
            $this->_dom = simplexml_load_file('Menu.xml');
            }

    }

    public function retrieveMenu($category)
    {       
        $products = $this->_dom->xpath('/menu/category[@name="'.$category.'"]');
        return $products;
    }
} // end of class Menu
```

Pretty rudimentary, I know, is just for testing purposes.
Now, I also have a XML file like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu>

    <category name="pizza">
        <item name="Tomato and Cheese">
            <type>Regular</type>
            <available>true</available>
            <size name="Small">
                <price>5.50</price>
            </size>
            <size name="Large">
                <price>9.75</price>
            </size>
        </item>
    </category>

    <category name="pizza">
        <item name="Pepperoni">
            <type>Regular</type>
            <available>true</available>
            <size name="Small">
                <price>6.85</price>
            </size>
            <size name="Large">
                <price>10.85</price>
            </size>
        </item>
    </category>
```

Which goes on with multiple products. So, the idea is to access this file through the class,
and to achieve that I'm doing the following in my index.php:

```
<?php
require 'Menu.php';
$menu = new Menu();
$tests = $menu->retrieveMenu('pizza');
foreach($tests as $test) {
    echo $test->attributes();
    echo '<br />';
    foreach($test->item as $item) {
        echo $item->attributes();
        echo '<br />';
        echo $item->type;
        echo '<br />';
        echo $item->available;
        echo '<br />';
        foreach($item->size as $price) {
            echo $price->attributes();
            echo '<br />';
            echo $price->price;
            echo '<br />';
            echo '<br />';
            echo $price->price;
            echo '<br />';*/
        }
        //echo $item->size->attributes();
        echo '<br /><br /><br /><br />';
    }
}
```

Which is given me back the results I'd expect:

```
>pizza
>Tomato and Cheese
>Regular
>true
>Small
>5.50
>Large
>9.75
```

Now, my question is: Since I'm using 3 nested for loops if I'm not wrong the complexity is n^3, which is pretty awful, the original XML contains lots of products, is there a better way of accessing it? Am I doing something wrong?

By the way, **YES, I MUST USE XML and XPATH**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the nested loops in this case. You access and output all the sub elements on a single resource. But yes it is possible with Xpath to fetch nodes from different levels into a list.

Xpath expressions can use | to combine several location paths. So its is actually three location paths and the expression returns all of the matching nodes:

1. `name` attribute nodes from all elements: `//*/@name`
2. child elements of `item` except `size`: `//item/*[not(self::size)]`
3. `price` child elements of `item/size`: `//item/size/price`

This example uses DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$expression = '//*/@name|//item/*[not(self::size)]|//item/size/price';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
  echo trim($node->nodeValue), "<br/>\n"; 
}
```

Output:

```
pizza<br/>
Tomato and Cheese<br/>
Regular<br/>
true<br/>
Small<br/>
5.50<br/>
Large<br/>
9.75<br/>
pizza<br/>
Pepperoni<br/>
Regular<br/>
true<br/>
Small<br/>
6.85<br/>
Large<br/>
10.85<br/>
```

A location path in Xpath works like a filter, the nodes are returned in an order depending on their position in the document.

It works with SimpleXML, too:

```
$element = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$expression = '//*/@name|//item/*[not(self::size)]|//item/size/price';

foreach ($element->xpath($expression) as $node) {
  echo trim($node), "<br/>\n"; 
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/156266

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I like better your version, it's more compact. One question though, would you please explain me a little better the expression?

Comment: I added some explanation.